# Why can't we use push and pop inside a procedure in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
    mov al,12
    mov ah,00
    mov cl,0
    convertBinary:
        cmp al,0
        je printBinary

        div two
        push ax
        inc cl

        mov ah,00
        jmp convertBinary

        printBinary:
            pop ax
            mov dl,ah
            add dl,48
            mov ah,02h
            int 21h
            loop printBinary
```

This code is working correctly without a procedure. When I put the same code inside a procedure and call it, then it says error due to the illegal instruction. Someone please explain me why we can't use those push and pop inside the procedures.

Comment: Please show exactly which code gets the error, and the exact error you get.

Comment: The `pop` at your `printBinary` label could occur without a corresponding `push` (e.g., if `al` is `0`). That would be bad.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a compiler, assemblers have no overall grammar for the whole file, just individual lines. Therefore the assembler doesn't even care that you're "inside a procedure" -- the names `convertBinary` and `printBinary` are just symbols that it can calculate relative addresses to from `jmp` and `loop` and `call` instructions.

Therefore, the same opcodes should be emitted by the assembler no matter what "context" you're in whether inside a procedure or not (not taking into account assembler directives to change the default operation size). I'm assuming you're getting illegal instruction at runtime, not when assembling the program?

Double check that you don't have any data right next to your code that is being overrun and overwriting the code at runtime, and that you're not missing any necessary control flow (a missing `ret` at the end of the procedure, or missing code to exit the program for example).

Also double check that you have a `push` instruction for each corresponding `pop`. Just because each instruction is present the same number of times in the code doesn't mean that each `push` and `pop` is being executed the same number of times.

Comment: I don't think that's what he meant by "inside a procedure"--rather, it goes boom when he calls it but it runs as a whole program.  The problem is two stack-trashing bugs in his code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work correctly for certain input states, it will go wild for others.  If it's inside a procedure when it goes wild it will do a wild jump if it doesn't get terminated on a stack fault first.

Run as the whole program (other than a termination call at the end) will avoid the wild jump although the wrong input will still produce bad output.

Look very carefully at your loop.  It doesn't do what you think.

Edit:  mbratch also brings up another failure case that I missed.